# Jenkins not showing all the Junit reports in the status of the build

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline

I have a maven build which contains multiple projects which in-turn contains lot of sub maven modules. At the test phase each project will execute their test and programatically I am generating junit test reports and put it in corresponding modules target folder in **/target/surefire-reports/**. After the build get success in the status page of the build in Jenkins I am able to see the test result as graph. But the problem is Jenkins is not taking all the generated junit xml it takes only partial amount of it.  I have totally 850 test cases in the whole build but it only shows 449 in the graph and test results. What will be the cause of it.

There is no problem in generating junit reports all the test cases are generating reports but the Jenkins is not able to identify all. The count of the test cases in Jenkins varies for each build without adding or removing any of the test files.

**FYI :**
  I am manually generating the junit reports. To notify it to Jenkins I have enabled the maven sure fire plugin and added the reports in surefire-reports folder in target. I have created **maven build project** not the **free style project**.

Is there is anything i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, and here are my thougths on it:
http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/02/sonar-jacoco-maven-multi-module.html

1. The issue is you need to concatenate the results into one report file.

So your pom should have something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <id>agent-for-ut</id>
    <goals>
     <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
     <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
   </execution>
   <execution>
    <id>agent-for-it</id>
    <goals>
     <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
     <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
   </execution>
  </executions>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

The keyword here is

```
<append>true</append>
```

Now all your data will be stored in 1 report file.

2. Make sure you have called your maven-surefire-plugin in only your parent pom. If you include it in your child poms as well, the results will be overwritten by the parent pom. More quirks here: http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/06/sonar-maven-surefire-plugin-quirks.html
3. Lastly make sure you are using junit and void methods correctly. Test for the side effects of the method or surefire will behave strangely.
   http://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#atests_4